# removing space from cell in an html table

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have an html table as

```
<table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <td><img src="image.jpg" width="600" height="170" style="padding:0; margin:0;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <p style="padding:0; margin:0;">Text</p>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Inspite of specifying the padding, margin as 0. I can see some white space between the image and the Text in Outlook 2003, 2002 email clients.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Try adding `border="0"` on the table tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're most likely seeing line-height of the `<td>`.  Use the following CSS to remove it, along with any whitespace:

```
/* Gets rid of table cell whitespace */
table td {
  line-height: 0;  
  font-size: 0;
}

/* Sets the font and line height correctly for the paragraph of text */
table td p {
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;   
}
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/RXs2K/).

Answer (score 0):

the answer above did not help me. for outlook 2003 try the following.

there is no css required.

just add vspace="0" hspace="0" on the image tag to remove the whitespace.

`<img src="........" vspace="0" hspace="0" />`

if your image has a link on it you can then take off the border with css by having border:none on the img tag and text-decoration with none on the a tag.

`<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
    <img src="imagename.jpg" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="border:none;" />
</a>`

take off padding on the td by adding padding of 0

`<td style="padding: 0;">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
        <img src="imagename.jpg" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="border:none;" />
    </a>
</td>`